# Is troika riding available as a tourist experience in Ukraine?

Tags: ukraine, winter-sports, animal-riding

Is troika riding available as a tourist experience in Ukraine? I tried searching, and could only find the slang usage of the term "troika". Is it specific only to Russia, and not a thing in Ukraine?

If it's available in Ukraine, is there anything available in late May or early June, either because of some place with a weird climate, an indoor snow area, or using alternative materials?

Comment: All you need is three horses and a sled. I'm pretty sure you can ride it anywhere in the world.

Comment: @JonathanReez You also need *snow*, which is not quite available anywhere in the world.

Comment: @gerrit troikas were sometimes used during the summer as well (with wheels obviously)

Comment: I think you will have hard time finding this as a tourist attraction. First of all, it's a rural area activity and it's absolutely not a tourist-friendly area. Next you'd need someone to have horses, harness for three horses and someone's desire to get this all together and ride you around - while there is nothing special in this combination, it will take some effort to find this in one place.

Comment: @Roman apart from MH17, corruption, crime, the conflict with Russia, lack of economic development, and the language barrier, is there any major reason to regard Ukraine as not tourist friendly?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, yeah, troika is an exclusively Russian experience, and I intentionally deluded you to motivate you to make own research :)

Comment: BTW, where did you ride troika in RF? It's a rather rare thing, usually tourists are offered a [small carriage](https://vk.com/ktkpetergof?w=product-16993431_18524%2Fquery)

Comment: @Suncatcher I've never been to Russia, and I don't have any plans to go there. I came across the word as vocabulary while studying Russian.

Comment: @Suncatcher "I intentionally deluded you to motivate you to make own research" - I mentioned that I'd tried doing some research, but that one of the keywords was polluted by slang meanings.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: important is that there is no tourist industry, no internal tourism, no infrastructure, no hotels, no tourist attractions and services around them, no directions, no convenient public transport network. That's where Ukraine is not tourist friendly, and not the standard set of superstitions you mentioned.

Comment: @RomanR. Did you mean "suppositions" rather than "superstitions"?

Comment: No, why? I mean superstitions. Corruption is nowhere near a problem for tourists. Crime is moderate: Ukraine is much safer than it might seem for a foreigner, and so on. Those are not the obstacles on Ukraine's way to being a touristic destination even though you mentioned them as such.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, I bet he meant *super-cliches* of propaganda he tried to broadcast and a bit blabbed out :)

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, If you are concerned about slang and other derivative meanings, you may rephrase the question to reflect the particular one you are interested in: "riding in a sleigh drawn by 3 horses, harnessed in certain particular fashion".

Comment: @mzu in my question, "I tried searching, and could only find the slang usage of the term " was referring to using a search engine, and they tend to prefer keywords rather than explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid that troika rides are not easily available in Ukraine. Online search on troika rides in Ukraine gives no meaningful results. I think I can explain why.

[Troika is a cultural icon of Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troika_(driving)), not Ukraine.  And seeing how are the [political relationship between Russia and Ukraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_military_intervention_in_Ukraine_(2014%E2%80%93present)) - nearly open hostilities - I would not expect to find troika rides available.

Ukraine was once a part of Russia/USSR and there are tendencies recently  to eliminate all cultural symbols related to the Russian/Soviet times. While troika is not an exemplary symbol in such respect, it is a symbol of Russia nevertheless. So, I would expect it to be difficult to operate troika rides from the current cultural and political standpoints.

Nearest place to Ukraine to ride troika would, in my opinion, be Russia. Multiple equestrian clubs are offering "an authentic Russian experience of riding Troika", such as: [1](http://zolotaya-griva.ru/katanie-na-russkoi-troike.htm) [2](http://kdkazachiyhutor.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B5/http://) [3](http://www.karetu.ru/winter.shtml) [4](http://hotel-yar.ru/services/russkaya-troyka.html) and many others (in Russian). English offering for foreign tourists are e.g. [here](http://www.bestrussiantour.com/daily_tours/russian_troika)